# ¿Por qué Bash me da el error de se esperaba una expresión entera?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, shell-script

Hola la verdad soy nuevo en esto de bash espero me puedan ayudar con mi siguiente codigo:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Ingrese el peso en Kilogramos (kg)"
read -r p  
echo "Ingrese la altura en metros (M)"
read -r a 
c=$(echo "scale=1; $p / ($a * $a)" | bc)

echo "Tu indice de masa corporal es" "$c"

if [ "$c" -gt 20 ]; then
        echo "Usted presenta desnutricion"
else
        echo "Usted Presenta obesidad"
fi
```

Al ejecutarlo como ***bash 1.sh*** ingreso los siguentes datos:

Ingrese el peso en kilgramos (kg) **96**

Ingrese la altura en metros (m) **1.86**

Tu indice de masa coporal es **27.8**

Y recibo el error:

```
1.sh: línea 9: [: 27.8: se esperaba una expresión entera
```

¿A que se refiere ese error? Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Porque el resultado de la cuenta de *bc* **No será un entero**, que es lo que necesita el comparador `[ x -gt y ]`.

En lugar de usar el *builtin* *[*, usa la evaluación aritmética:

```
if (( $c > 20 )); then
...
```